# Automatically Generating API Token in Strapi for Development

Tags: authentication, devops, strapi

I'm currently working on a project using Strapi and Nextjs (they are seperated from each other), and I'm trying to streamline our development process by automatically obtaining an authentication token. This would help me avoid repetitive manual steps during development: opening the Strapi web interface, creating an API token and exporting it as an env var for my Nextjs app.

Do you guys have a cool solution for this?

I tried creating a Nodejs script to generate an admin user and save an api token in the strapi database. But not I am not sure if this is the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to apply a token on Strapi v4:

```
const tokenService = strapi.service('admin::api-token');

const attributes = {
    name: `token${getRandomID()}`,
    description: '',
    type: 'full-access',
    lifespan: null,
    // type: "custom",
    // permissions: [
    //    "api::restaurant.restaurant.find",
    // ]
};

const apiToken = await tokenService.create(attributes);
```

reference: https://forum.strapi.io/t/v4-unit-testing/14818/34?page=2

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean to create an API token to access your Strapi APIs?

If so, you can use the API Tokens option in your Strapi Settings (Link at `/admin/settings/api-tokens/create`), then select expiry and the API operations that you wish to whitelist for your project. You can then put the API token generated in your NextJS project and pass the token as the Authorization header.

[image: API Tokens page]

Comment: thank you for your answer but not exactly

i know that you can manually create api tokens via the interface and copy it over to the nextjs project but i want to automatically generate a token for the developers on that repo, so that they don't have to go to the interface and generate it themselves

basically what i want is the following: a developer joins as a contributor and he runs a setup script and everything is set up for development also the api token, so that he doesn't need to go to strapi's interface and do it manually